# How to create a new column of ranges (about 50 ranges) based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda, range

I have a data frame which essentially looks like this:

| number | value |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 0 |
| 201 | 1 |
| 202 | 2 |
| .. | .. |
| 399 | 3 |
| 400 | 4 |

What I want to do is to create a new column which has the range of 3 consecutive numbers:

| number | value | range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 0 | 200 - 202 |
| 201 | 1 | 200 - 202 |
| 202 | 2 | 200 - 202 |
| .. | .. | .. |
| 399 | 3 | 398 - 400 |
| 400 | 4 | 398 - 400 |

One thing I can do is to create my own function and write if statements like this:

```
def function(number):

    if number < 203 & number > 199:
        return "200-202"
    elif number < 206 & number > 202:
        return "203-205"
    ....
    and so on
```

But this would require I write about 70 if statements. I'm sure there is an easier way to do this. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: What is the logic for the range? In other words, why is number `201` in range `200-202` and not `201-203`?

Comment: So these numbers are the week numbers, which I have assigned based on date ranges. Now the final dataframe starts from week 200, and I am trying to collapse this dataframe by 3 weeks.

Comment: So numbers are consecutive without missing number?

Comment: `pd.cut(df['numbers'], bins=range(200,400, 2))`, play with the bins

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the range from the number itself.

Assuming you want to start on the first value and use ranges of n=3, you can use:

```
n = 3
first = df['number'].iloc[0]   # initial value (could be set to 0 to have fixed ranges)
start = (df['number']
         .sub(first).floordiv(n)
         .mul(n).add(first)
         )

df['range'] = start.astype(str)+'-'+start.add(n-1).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
   number  value    range
0     200      0  200-202
1     201      1  200-202
2     202      2  200-202
3     399      3  398-400
4     400      4  398-400
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pd.cut`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': range(200,400),
    'b': np.random.randint(0,10,200)
})
wks = 2
x.loc[:,'range'] = pd.cut(x.a, bins=range(x.a.min(), x.a.max()+wks, wks), right=False)
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows',5):
    display(x)
```

Output:

```
    a   b   range
0   200 7   [200, 202)
1   201 6   [200, 202)
... ... ... ...
198 398 1   [398, 400)
199 399 3   [398, 400)
```

After which I presume you want to do something like:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows',5):
    display(x.groupby('range').b.sum())
```

Output:

```
range
[200, 202)    13
[202, 204)     6
              ..
[396, 398)     6
[398, 400)     4
Name: b, Length: 100, dtype: int32
```